# Just get first json property?

Tags: php, json, url

I'm trying to get the json property's from an url. But just the first property arrives.

```
        $json = file_get_contents('http://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?currency=3&appid=730&market_hash_name=' . $item_name);
        $obj = json_decode($json, true);
        $result = count($obj);
        echo $json;
```

**Output is:**

```
"{"success":true}"
```

**instead of:**

```
"{"success":true,"lowest_price":"0,96\u20ac","volume":"143","median_price":"0,89\u20ac"}"
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: use `print_r($obj);`

Comment: What's an example of `$item_name`?

Comment: Try to use `json_last_error_msg` to see if there is an error

Comment: @cmorrissey In there is just the success property. 
Array ( [success] => 1 )

Comment: @JonStirling Something like that: sAK-47 | Redline (Field-Tested)

Comment: I can't get the URL to give me anything other than the success false JSON with that example...

Comment: @JonStirling ouhh. Thanks i got it. I have forgot to convert the $item_name into an url with urlencode()